# How can I declare two different configurations to .stylelint

Tags: styles, stylelint, scss-lint

I use Stylelint on my project to check styles.
I'm using a plugin that should only run on one folder. And the main configuration that is done for the whole project.
**.stylelint** file:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "plugins": [
        "stylelint-scss",
        "stylelint-no-px"
     ],
    "rules": {
        ...
    }
}
```

and run command:  `"stylelint": "stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\""`.
But i have to use `"stylelint-no-px"` pluggin only on src/app folder

There was an idea to create two launch commands for different folders(`src/app` and whole `src`), but in this case `app` folder would be checked twice.

Is there any way to create two different configs that could inherit from each other? For example, the first one is called only on `src/app` folder, and the second without a plugin is called on `src/` folder and excludes `src/app` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`overrides` configuration property](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#overrides) to modify a Stylelint config for a specified set of files.

For example, to additionally run the stylelint-no-px plugin on the `*.scss` files in the `src/app` directory:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "plugins": [
        "stylelint-scss",
        "stylelint-no-px"
     ],
    "rules": {
        ... // don't include meowtec/no-px here
    },
    "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["src/app/*.scss", "src/app/**/*.scss"],
      "rules": {
        "meowtec/no-px": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then continue to run Stylelint only once using the following command:

```
stylelint "src/**/*.scss"
```